# PHP echo only returning 1 digit results

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, joomla2.5

When I query the DB itself, both queries return the correct number of results. However, when I drop this code into Joomla 2.5, it will only return up to the number 9. After that, if there's more, it will only display the first digit. So, basically, 11 should be the result, but it will only display 1. Please help!

```
SELECT count( * ) as column_name FROM `db`  
WHERE column_name >= DATE_FORMAT(NOW('0000-00-00'), '%Y-%m-01')
```

The echo within the PHP: `<?php echo $column_name [0]; ?>`

Comment: That SQL statement is invalid syntax. The `NOW()` function does not take an argument. If this query did return a resultset, it would contain exactly one row, due to the `COUNT()` aggregate in the `SELECT` list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `<?php echo $column_name; ?>`, the `[0]` you've added means "the first character of the string", so you'll receive 1 for 12, or 4 for 42.

Comment: Perfect! Works perfectly now. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try this `<?php echo $column_name; ?>`
instead of `<?php echo $column_name [0]; ?>`

`$column[0]` is fetching the first letter/digit from your result which is why you are not getting the complete result.